# What is the relationship between the volume form and the divergence operator?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

While researching how to derive the divergence theorem from the generalized Stokes' theorem, I ran into the [wikipedia page for the volume form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form#Divergence), which claimed that the divergence of a vector field $X$ on a manifold $M$ could be defined as the unique scalar function which solves
$$(\textrm{div}X)\omega = d(X \;\lrcorner\;\omega) \quad (1)$$
where $\omega$ is the volume form of $M$ and $X \;\lrcorner\;\omega$ is the interior product with $X$.
Stokes' theorem then implies that
$$ \int_{M} (\textrm{div}X)\omega = \int_{\partial M}X \;\lrcorner\;\omega \quad (2)$$

This is claimed to be a generalization of the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem).

1. Why is $(1)$ a "good" definition for divergence? How does it connect to the usual definition? How should I (intuitively) interpret the relation with the volume form?
2. How does $(2)$ restrict to the usual statement of the divergence theorem? I'd assume there's some way to transform $X \;\lrcorner\;\omega$ into $(X\cdot n) \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the volume form on $\partial M$, but I don't know how to derive it.

Comment: Here's a suggestion for you to get started. Work it out when $X$ is a vector field on a compact $3$-dimensional submanifold with boundary $M\subset \Bbb R^3$ (so  $\omega = dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$). For (2), if $X=(P,Q,R)$, show that $P\,dy\wedge dz + Q\,dz\wedge dx + R\,dx\wedge dy$ is $(X\cdot n)\alpha$ by showing first that this expression restricts to the $0$-form on $\partial M$ when $X\cdot n = 0$, i.e., when $X$ is tangent to $\partial M$.